# Correction Term

Tags: estimation, spheres

I am reading a paper where they do some estimation of the mass of a sphere (they assume the density is constant). Then they talk about the order of the leading correction term being e.g. $O(k/N)$. I am wondering what they mean by the "correction term".

My guess is that it is the terms that differ between the estimate and the true value of the mass. Is this correct? If not, how do you define the "correction term"?

Comment: Without the paper itself and some indication of what the terms $k$ and $N$ mean in context, its tough to answer. However they probably are able to express the mass a series of terms related to the density and the simplest term uses a constant density while later terms account for its variation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The paper is [Estimating Mutual Information, Kraskov (2004)](https://juser.fz-juelich.de/record/42907/files/60015.pdf) and the part I am confused about is the paragraph directly after eq(20) if that helps.